# Implement the SUM function (without addition or bitwise operator) using the provided async ADD function

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, settimeout, event-loop

I have given an asyncAdd function with the usage of sum function and asked to provide the correct sum function

```
function asyncAdd(a, b, cb) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    cb(null, a + b)
  }, Math.floor(Math.random) * 1000);
}

// Implement sum function to match the below usage


(async() => {
  const result1 = await sum(1, 2, 3)
  const result2 = await sum(3, 5, 4, 7)
  console.log([result1, result2]) //[6, 21]
})();
```

I have tried to implement sum function as below but could not figure out what is the callback or this is even the right approach.

```
async function sum(...args) {
  let total = 0;
  
  for (const arg of args) {
    total = await asyncAdd(total, arg, ??)
  }
  
  return total;
}
```

Comment: `asyncAdd` doesn't return a promise, so `await asyncAdd` won't do what you expect

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that i added the "async" to asyncAdd function in order to use await on the sum function

Comment: Please may you not remove the effort you've already made?

Comment: I figured the solution is totally wrong and i should not make change to the asyncAdd function so i removed it

Comment: You've made an effort. Showing that, however wrong, is _always_ better than asking without it. (imo)